# how to get authorize code for adultwork using python

Tags: python, rest

Given the rest api instruction on the site:

https://developers.adultwork.com/Site/UnifiedLogin/AuthorizationCode

Having tried a number of variants from the many available resources all of which throw 400 type errors (usually 404 or 405 error), would like to have a piece of code such as:

```
def get_access_token():
    url = 'https://api.adultwork.com' + '/OAuth/Authorize'
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
    auth=(cr.api_key, cr.api_secret)

    r = requests.get(url, data=data, auth=auth)
    print(r.status_code)
    return r
```

There appear to only be a few components, so presumably the above is a close guess.

The credential strings `cr.api_key` and `cr.api_secret` are given to the user which presumably are sufficient for the above.

So the question is how to implement this (in python) to get the access code ?
An explanation would be most helpful too.

Comment: The site is not opening, so can't say what is wrong here.

Comment: Same problem here, provide a valid url

Comment: that is part of the question:  what is a valid url ?   https://developers.adultwork.com/en-GB/Site/API/Reference    which points to these two bases.    Sandbox, base URI: https://api-sandbox.adultwork.com
Live, base URI : https://api.adultwork.com

Comment: They have a "Request Support" link at the bottom of their site. Perhaps you should start there. Otherwise, try getting just `curl` or PostMan (this is even recommended by that site) to work, then you can more easily use tools that can **generate** Python code for you

Comment: @OneCricketeer ,  thanks for the comment.  the support is slow (24 hrs) and also keep referring to we help pages. The code should be relatively simple for a person familiar with REST API (which i clearly am not), hence the question...

Comment: The API page clearly refers to Postman, so start there https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: I have read the documentation multiple times and do not understand the format or how to correct the error. Hence why asking assuming somebody knows.  I have gone as far back as here:  https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/, but cannot figure out what to do.